# Inner bindings in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda, syntax

I'm new in Haskell, and
I don't get it how this code works. Can anyone please explain it to me **how the inner binding works** in this example:

```
f = (\x -> ((\x -> x*x) 3)+x)
```

when I try  `f 1` I get `10`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You code is quite obfuscated, so let’s clean it up. We start with

```
f = (\x -> ((\x -> x*x) 3)+x)
```

and notice that there are two variables that are both called `x` – how confusing! So let’s write this as

```
f = (\x -> ((\y -> y*y) 3)+x)
```

Next, there is this inner lambda expression. We can give it a name and bind it at the same level as `f` is bound:

```
square = (\y -> y*y)
f = (\x -> (square 3)+x)
```

At this point, I would like to remove unnecessary parenthesis:

```
square = \y -> y*y
f = \x -> square 3 + x
```

and finally, instead using a lambda abstraction, we can define `square` and `f` as functions. Again, this is equivalent code¹:

```
square y = y*y
f x = square 3 + x
```

At this point, you can probably make more sense of this code.

¹ <sup>In fact, the compiler might optimize the two different when it comes to *inlining*, which happens only when all *manifest* arguments are provided, but that is beyond the scope of this question.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can safely remove the outer parentheses:

```
f = \x -> ((\x -> x*x) 3) + x
```

Now, the `\x -> stuff` construct is an anonymous function of one argument `x`. The very inner function `\x -> x*x` squares any given number. `(\x -> x*x) 3` calls it, which gives you `3 * 3 == 9`.

The outer function calls the inner one first and adds `x` to the result. So, you get `9 + 1 == 10`.

I don't see anything special about binding here. The functions are independent, as well as the variables `x`.